# Creating a widget to open mini-cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget

I have a plugin which adds a mini cart to my [website](https://browns.kurvecreative.co.uk) so when I add a product to the basket the mini cart pops out from the page.

The whole plugin works great. The only thing I want to do is create a widget to put in the header area of the website to open the mini cart, just like the hovering basket does in the bottom right hand corner of the page.

The code that it says to use is:

```
public_woo_amc_show()
```

The problem is, that I'm totally unsure, how to add a custom widget. I've googled and managed to code this code:

```
// Register and load the widget
function wpb_load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'wpb_widget' );
}

add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_load_widget' );

// Creating the widget 
class wpb_widget extends WP_Widget {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(

            // Base ID of your widget
            'wpb_widget',

            // Widget name will appear in UI
            __( 'WPBeginner Widget', 'wpb_widget_domain' ),

            // Widget description
            array( 'description' => __( 'Sample widget based on WPBeginner Tutorial', 'wpb_widget_domain' ), )
        );
    }

    // Creating widget front-end
    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $instance['title'] );

    // before and after widget arguments are defined by themes
        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( ! empty( $title ) ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

    // This is where you run the code and display the output
        echo __( 'Hello, World!', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    // Widget Backend 
    public function form( $instance ) {
        if ( isset( $instance['title'] ) ) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            $title = __( 'New title', 'wpb_widget_domain' );
        }

        // Widget admin form
        ?>
        <p>
            <label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Title:' ); ?></label>
            <input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id( 'title' ); ?>"
                   name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name( 'title' ); ?>" type="text"
                   value="<?php echo esc_attr( $title ); ?>"/>
        </p>
        <?php
    }

    // Updating widget replacing old instances with new
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance          = array();
        $instance['title'] = ( ! empty( $new_instance['title'] ) ) ? strip_tags( $new_instance['title'] ) : '';

        return $instance;
    }
} // Class wpb_widget ends here
```

All I want is an icon that I can click and it pops the mini-cart out exactly how it does on the website above already.

I've tried adding this code where I thought it would go within this widget but I'm no expert and am definitely limited with JavaScript.

Comment: What kind of program u use to program? Maybe you should inform yourself about the pretty print function of your program. Any this is PHP and not JavaScript at all (Just to say). I'll edit your question for you.

Comment: To make a cart like on your example website, you need basic knowledge about CSS, a bit of JavaScript and PHP at all. Maybe you should do some tutorials to understand the programming language because StackOverflow isn't a free coding service.

Comment: The cart is already there and functioning like I said I just want it so when I click the button it opens the cart that is already there but thanks for the help anyway. I have knowledge of CSS and very basic knowledge of certain aspects of PHP

Comment: But if you have knowledge, you can add a custom button with a JS function onClick which opens the cart. Where is the problem?

Comment: Basic knowledge is my problem. Never mind i'll ask on a useful website rather than know it all's who clearly started from somewhere and needed a helping hand once upon a time. 3 time's I have asked a question on this website which seems to be basic (at least I know this question is!) and all people seem to be interested in is editing your post and commenting with totally non-topic and unhelpful comments.

Comment: I don't understand you. If you want a button that pops it out, you can google and you'll find so many tutorials about buttons and click events in JavaScript. You may not find an exact how-to with code but you find the logic how to perform this and then you can try to get it running. If you fail, you can post your code here. But at the moment people need to build a button, a function, the css and all the stuff and this is just code the things for you which is not the goal from StackOverflow. We will see your tries! And if you don't try, you'll not come forward.